# Почему при нажатии кнопки, она перекидывает в самый вверх?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
 body {
        width: 1360px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0;
    }
    header {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: 240px;
     background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
.logo {
margin-top: 38px;
margin-left: 100px;
}
.menu {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #1d1d1d; 
}
.text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.indent {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-indent: 610px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: right;
}
.menu a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightskyblue;
}
.work {
    height: 930px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.work1 {
    color: #1d1d1d;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
.work2 {
    color: #818181;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 27px;
}
.work3{
    color: #818181;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.video {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1170px;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.radius {
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    border-radius:80px;
    background-color: #10c9c3;
    border:1px solid #10c9c3;
    margin-top: 247px;
    margin-left: 520px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="uft-8">
<title> </title>
<header>
<img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
<div class="menu"> 
<a href="#" onMouseOut='getElementyById' (menu1).style.display="none";
onMouseover="getElementyById" (menu1).style.display="block";><p class="text indent">HOME</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">ABOUT</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu3).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">WORK</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu4).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">PROCESS</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu5).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">SERVICES</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu6).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">TESTIMONIALS</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu7).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">CONTACT</p></a>  
</div>
</header>
<div class="work">
<h3 class="work1">Our Work Process</h3>
<p class="work2">Was years it seasons was there form he in in them together over that, </p>
<p class="work3">third sixth gathered female creeping bearing behold years.</p>
<!--div for video-->
<div class="video">
    <form>
        <button class="radius">
     <img src="arrow.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle">
    </button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Есть ли способ избавиться от этого или так должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вверх переходит потому, что у ссылки стоит `href`, который говорит, что надо перейти на страницу с таким url. А раз там `#` То просто страница возвращается к началу.

Можно:

1) Повесить на клик по `a` обработчик, который будет предотвращать стандартное поведение по клику на ссылку (сделать preventDefault или return false)

2) Заменить тег `a` на любой другой тег. Зачем нужна ссылка, если она никуда не ведет?